# Really new to Python, just wondering what I did wrong here

Tags: python

```
import random

varA = random.randint(0,20)

print(varA)

if (varA == 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8):
    print("set 1")

elif(varA == 9 or 10 or 11 or 12 or 13 or 14 or 15):
    print("set 2")

elif(varA == 16 or 17 or 18 or 19 or 20):
    print("set 3")
```

So no matter what number varA becomes, it prints "set 1." I know it's probably something ridiculously obvious but I'm extremely new to Python and programming overall, I was just messing around with elif and can't figure what's wrong here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Or` doesn't really work like the English or. You should do it as this instead:

```
if (varA in range(9)):
    print("set 1")

elif(varA in range(9,16)):
    print("set 2")

elif(varA in range(16,21)):
    print("set 3")
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
if (0 =< varA <= 8):
    print("set 1")

elif (9 =< varA <= 15):
    print("set 2")

elif (16 =< varA <= 20):
    print("set 3")
```

Comment: While the part about `or` not working like English is true, `in range(anything)` is a horrible habit to get into.

Comment: @user2357112. I have suggested an alternate method. Thank you

Comment: Again, you can also do `if (0 <= varA <= 8):`

Comment: Thanks for the answers (that goes out to everyone), I had organized them without "or" earlier but was creating the range incorrectly I guess so I figured I'd try to be as thorough as possible which is when I started using "or" In any case, thanks again everyone!

Comment: @user3514234, if my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you.

Comment: I had to think a minute about the Problem with `in range()`, resulting in a comparison of (worst case) each element. If python only had a type system and a properly overloaded `in` operator for ranges...

Comment: @ted: Python *does* have a type system. What are you talking about? It's just that in the 2.x line, `range` returns a list for historical reasons. `xrange` is bare-bones, so it doesn't support efficient `in` for simplicity, but Python 3 `range` objects have an efficient `in` operator.

Comment: @user2357112 While I did not look that much into the details of `in`, that is sort of the point. I fail to see the issue with a properly overloaded `__contains__`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (varA == 0 or varA == 1 ...):
    print("set 1")
```

You need to compare `1` against `varA` again, you can't do `VarA == 0 or 1` because that will theoreticly check if `1` is `True`, which it is.

So i could translate your code into:

```
if (varA == 0 or 1 == True or 2 == True ...)
```

Any number of 1 or more will become True.
This is the reason why your code fails, @sshashank beat me to the `range()` solution so i'll be satisfied with simply explaining where you went wrong.

Comment: Why the downvote? This answers the OP's question and further more explains why it fails.. which no one else explained....

Answer (score 1):

```
if varA in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]:
```

Better:

```
if varA >= 0 and varA < 8:
```

Even better:

```
if 0 <= varA < 8:
```

Comment: Even better: `if 0 <= var < 8:`

Comment: @Torxed: Wrong direction on the `>=`.

Comment: @user2357112 Heh yepp, well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

The `or` statements in the `if` statement will always make the expression true. This is because you are doing a logical or on values `1, 2, 3...` which will always be true.